# Where (and in what format) to store html code of a page within another html page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have a page that has an iframe with src=... etc

I need to build the same page but make it work off-line. One page, no multiple pages.

So I will do an http get, get the contents of the page in the iframe and try to store the html code in the main page. Then, onload, I will create an iframe on the fly and I will try to populate the iframe with the html code I stored earlier.

So, the stored html code will have `<html><head>` etc. The question is where to store the html code in the page (and in what format) in order to access it later?

In an `<object>` element?

In a `<div>` element?

In a JSON object or JavaScript variable?

Other idea?

Answer (score 1):

in your filesystem you could also  store the second html-document in the same folder  and refference to it like

```
src="framecontent.html"
```

Comment: This will only work if the original page is downloaded to, and run from the local file system. If the page is loaded from a server the page doesn't have access to the local filesystem.

Comment: okay, so you actually dont have acces right to the files on file-system on the server, i thought so

Answer (score 0):

For your main page: create an [offline app](http://diveintohtml5.info/offline.html). If the content of the `<iframe>` is under your control, do the same for that page too. Your users will need to visit the online version once, after which the browser will cache the pages and serve them locally.  No need to worry about storage: the browser will do it all for you.

If the `<iframe>` is not under your control, put it in `localStorage` (reference [here](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html)). Your other suggestions won't persist over a page load.